# Cannot extend controller in cake

Tags: php, cakephp, constructor, cakephp-2.0

In one of my controllers, trying to do nothing extra in the constructor but run it's parent constuctor:

```
public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
}
```

I receive the error "Call to a member function body() on a non-object". Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: post the code from the parent

Comment: Also have a look at the line-number and filename in the error-message, that way you'll be able to locate 'where' to look for the problem. CakePHP outputs a neat 'error stack', which you can unfold and see which parts of code are executed and in what order

Comment: Also, if you're NOT doing anything inside your constructor, you can remove the constructor from your extended class as it will automatically be inherited from the parent-class

Answer (score 3):

Why not just taking a look at the file you are trying to extend?
Cake is open source after all. Then you would easily find out what kind of constructor you would need ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L317 )

```
public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
    parent::__construct($request, $response);
}
```